# How can I write the name of an image and its coordinates into a save.txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, save

How would I write "if sticker1 is placed and in the array" then... My goal is for the sticker to be placed and entered into the array as a name with coordinates then saved to a save.txt file. From there, I can click a load button and it will load the sticker and place it at the exact coordinates.

```
if (hatSoundPlay){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
sticker1.arraysticker(hatPicture, "hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
image ++;//increments image by 1
arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 1 into the array
```

Then for the save code.

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < arraysticker.length; i++);
    if (sticker1.images[images].isShowing){
    //I want the iff statement ^^ to say if sticker if placed in the array
    //fw.write name and coords into save.txt    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have class `Stricker`, which should looks like this :

```
public class Sticker(){
  private String name;
  private int X;
  private int Y;

  //There You should place Getters and Setters to variables name,X and Y
  //... and your method named 'arraysticker(Object, Image, Integer, Integer)'
}
```

... next step is to create the correct type of list `ArrayList<Sticker> list = new ArrayList<>();`

I'll do this like that:

```
if(hatSoundPlay){ 
   hatsound.play(); 
   Sticker sticker1 = new Sticker();

   sticker1.arraysticker(hatPicture, "hat.png", clickX, clickY);

   image ++;
   list[image] = sticker1;
}
```

and finally at your save code should looks like:

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
   for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
       if(list[i]!=null){ //if object exist, do...
         String name;
         int x,y;

         name = list.getName();
         x = list.getX();
         y = list.getY();

         fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n"); //write all elements to file separated with space and symbol of new line
       }
    }
  fw.close(); //necessary to close connection with file
}
```

To solve this problem I need rest of code, because I don't have information about Yours methods and otherr arrays like `images`

Answer (score 0):

As far as you need save and restore objects, I suggest you to use some ready solutions like Jackson library. This simplifies the logic and you can control what to save and restore just by using annotations.

There are a lot of examples. So you get your class, mark properties with annotations and that is. Jackson lib will do everything for you. Take a look this tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial